# Authorize a request in spring security using method level security

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization

I am working on web application development using spring and hibernate. The requirement is to implement Role based authorization using method level security.

My application is divided into two part -

- **Login API** -Login API basically provided username/password authentication using database and will generate a token.
- **Main API** - This API is responsible for all other functionalities.

The first and last(login/logout) request from client will be handled by login-api and rest of the request will go to main-api.
In order to authenticate request in main-api I have a interceptor in main-api which will eventually call a method of login-api to authenticate the request.
So at main-api authentication is done by login-api, however I want to authorize each request at main-api based on custom roles which are defined in database.

*Following is my sample controller in main-api*

```
@RestController
public class HealthController {

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(path = "/health", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<String> getHealth() {
    System.out.println("HealthController");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello User!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

I really don't know how to defined custom roles and authorize request based on it.

Following is sample WebSecurityConfiguration class that I found on google. I see username/password and roles are hard coded here. 
In my case I have userId and based on that I have to fetch roles from database and check for authorization.

I hope what I have requested is possible.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("greg").password("turnquist").roles("ADMIN").and()
            .withUser("ollie").password("gierke").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .httpBasic().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/health").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
    .csrf().disable();
}
}
```

Comment: You say your login api generates a token... Is your interceptor in main-api populating the SecurityContextHolder's Authentication?